# Is UNIQUE(), INDEX() different from UNIQUE INDEX()?

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, unique-constraint

Is there any different how mysql treats

```
UNIQUE (column1, column2),
INDEX (column1)
```

and

```
UNIQUE INDEX (column1, column2)
```

and

```
UNIQUE (column1, column2)
```

In the latter, I think mysql will automatically creates index for `UNIQUE` to avoid duplicate records. Am I right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UNIQUE (column1, column2)` implies `UNIQUE INDEX (column1, column2)` because the `INDEX` keyword is optional. So an index is created. <strike>However, the [MySQL 5.5 docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) show that the `INDEX` (or `KEY`) keyword is mandatory so `UNIQUE (column1, column2)` should give an error</strike>

`INDEX (column1, column2)` does not mean `UNIQUE INDEX (column1, column2)`: it means an index that *does* allow duplicate `(column1, column2)` pairs

Comment: @gbn: The linked page has this: `[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] UNIQUE [INDEX|KEY]`, so `UNIQUE (column1, column2)` does not give an error. Neither in 5.1, nor in 5.5.

Comment: @ypercube: oh yeah, read the docs wrong!

Answer (score -1):

The second and and third are equivalent.

The first is like the third, but adds a (non-unique) index in addition to the unique index. Which is unnecessary and wasteful.